# how to use css in codeigniter

Tags: html, css

i have code views like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- mendeskripsikan ke browser type karakter yang digunakan -->
    <meta http-equivn="Content-Type" content="text/html: charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Smells like Bakin Cupcake Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container clearfix" >
        <div class="grid_4">
            <img src="asset/img/logo.gif" alt="Smells Like Bakin">
        </div>
        <div class="grid_8 omega">  
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('home/about'); ?>"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cupcake &amp; Prices</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

i include this code in page home.php css working when i include in about.php css is not working.
can you help me? thank you

Comment: run the code into chrome ,press `f12` and check `css` file is loaded or not

Comment: the file is not loaded. how?

Answer (score 0):

you code should be

```
<link href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/style.css” rel=”stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

check [urlhelper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) doc

also the default location for css files is the same level as the application i.e.,

```
/css
/application
```

Check the path as has been suggested.

Comment: i has been try this but its same not working. iam so confused

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion bes way is to use URL helper.

You can autoload it in `config/autoload.php` using `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
and then in your view file use code like:

```
<link href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

PS. In the first answer posted by Radian is a mistake. Two times used `”` insted of `"`